# On exactness of associating smooth representation-functor $(\,)^\infty$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, profinite-groups, short-exact-sequences

Let $G$ be a locally profinite group, e.g. reductive group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. For a (abstract) representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ and $K\subset G$ compact open subgroup denote by $V^K\subset V$ the $\pi(K)$-fixed vectors in $V$. Then $(\pi,V)$ is said do be smooth if
\begin{equation*}
V=\bigcup_K V^K 
\end{equation*}
where $K$ ranges over all compact open subgroups of $G$. For any representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ we define
\begin{equation*}
V^\infty=\bigcup_K V^K 
\end{equation*}
where $K$ ranges again over all compact open subgroups of $G$. That is a $G$-stable subspace of $V$ and thus defines a smooth representation $(\pi^\infty,V^\infty)$. Furthermore $(\,)^\infty$ is a left exact functor from $G$-representations to smooth $G$-representations.

Are there mild conditions on $G$ or on the representations of $G$ when it is exact?

Comment: Do you have a particular application in mind?

Comment: I had, but I found a solution for my problem which was proven with other methods. Should I delete the question?